# In an ArrayCollection need to count the records in a field

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, arraycollection

Flash Builder 4, AS3.

In an ArrayCollection need to count the records in a field, for example need to know how many users have age of 25. This is the ArrayCollection dataProvider for my DataGrid.

In SQL is easy, just need the command:
select age, count (age) from employees where age = '25';

But ArrayCollection tried several ways and could not, could someone help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work assuming the `ArrayCollection` has objects with a field `age`:

```
var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([ { "name":"test1", "age":25 }, { "name":"test1", "age":20 }, { "name":"test1", "age":25 } ]);
var count:int = 0;
for each (var item:Object in ac) 
{
    if (item.age == 25)
        ++count;
}
trace(count);
```

Comment: +1; This is the most direct approach. You could also apply a filter to the ArrayCollection and then use the length after the ArrayCollection is applied.  That would also have display implications on any components using the collection as a dataProvider, though.